# Flutter project debug is stopping in my Redmi note 9 phone

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2003J15SC in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

Invalid depfile: D:\Kampus\Alternative Internship\E-Butler FLutter\history-ebutler-main\.dart_tool\flutter_build\8db1b350320c9cfb508a70518c727e07\kernel_snapshot.d


Parameter format not correct -

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly

Error launching application on M2003J15SC.

Exited (sigterm)
```

when i press f5 on my vscode the build is success but in my phone only view white screen and then it exited

Answer (score 1):

Just switch off the `Turn on MIUI Optimization` in your `Developer options` then run your app.

For some other fixes checkout [this](https://silicon-insider.com/fix-install_failed_user_restricted-error-android-studio-using-redmi-devices/).

Answer (score 1):

Your app is installed even if your phone stays on white screen, you can see that it worked by closing and reopening the app from your phone.

This Issue happens on most Xiaomi...Redmi note 10 pro as well this is only when it comes to flutter, if you launch project from root/android it will work fine,
If you use command line `flutter run` it will also work but you will not get input back from command line after install only difference app is launching
At the moment this is the only worked around

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app meets the following requirements:
Targets API level 19 (KitKat) or higher Uses Android 4.4 or higher

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

in some android devices not receiving firbase base responce because of its versions and api level

Comment: the app already meet the requirements, two days ago i can debug this app, but since yesterday the miui is updated then the error comes

Comment: minSdkVersion ?

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean, restart your devices, reconnect your devices to your pc and run again, this solution worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).